# GetFullPath returns a weird result

Tags: powershell

Please have a look at the following snippet

```
PS D:\.m3dia w0rks\.crossfade> [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath("..\.cf_test")
D:\WorkDT\.cf_test
```

GetFullPath returns a result that is not relative to the current path, but to a different path which I have no idea where it comes from. The weird path IS valid, I do have such a folder, but where does it come from into this picture?

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath()` resolves the path relative to `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory`, not `$PWD`

Comment: @Mathias Wow! Thanks for the answer. This is kind of stupid, why are there two current directories? What's the big idea?

Comment: PowerShell providers are not necessarily file system based, (try `cd cert:` or `cd hklm:`), so changing the process directory in sync with the location stack in PowerShell would not be consistent

Comment: @Mathias I get it, thanks. Now I feel puny :( I'm gonna go RTFM.

Comment: We all live and learn :-)